# Java - parsing ä ö ü

Tags: java

Sorry for my bad English, i'm from Germany, but i hope, i'm understandable.

```
String = Dömä
Result = D(any signs)m(any signs)
```

My Code:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(UserFactory.GET_URL, "POST", paramsx);
                sList = new ArrayList<Data>();
                JSONArray cast = json.getJSONArray("friends");
                for (int i = 0; i < cast.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject actor = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                    String fullname = actor.getString("fullname");
                    String country = actor.getString("country");
                    String profile_image = actor.getString("profile_image");
                    sList.add(new Data(fullname, country, profile_image));
                }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment that you tried UTF-8 and that it didn't work.  How did you implement it?  Where are you using this encoding?  Which string came across with the umlauts?

Comment: How did you print out the result? Try `System.out.println("äöü")`. As long as that doesn't work correctly there is no point in printing out the result. To print out umlauts at the console you first need to compile the .java file with javac -encoding utf8 source.java if your IDE doesn't do that automatically. Next you need to know what encoding the console uses you are printing to. If it's a windows cmd console you need to use cp850 by putting this line at the start of your main method. `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "cp850"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with your character encoding. You need to make sure the character encoding you are using for the JSON supports the language you are using and that both ends of the link are using the same encoding.

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: @CagoDeggah use UTF-8. Google it and you will find plenty of examples.

Comment: its work:
String fullname = new String(actor.getString("fullname").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");